# No projects listed with Maps Engine Lite API

Tags: api, google-maps

I've set up API service account access and that seems to be authenticating and connecting OK using the provided sample code (https://developers.google.com/maps-engine/documentation/oauth/serviceaccount).

I've shared my map with the provided service account email address in the Google Maps Engine UI.

Accessing the API method https://www.googleapis.com/mapsengine/v1/projects I expected to see my map in a returned list of projects visible to the service account. Instead, only an empty projects array is returned.

Ultimately my goal is to access place name and geodata stored within a layer on the map I have created in Maps Engine Lite. Is there a step I have missed or something I have misunderstood about granting API access to a Maps Engine Lite map?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out certain features, such as the ones I was looking to use, are only available on the (paid for) Maps Engine, and not "Maps Engine Lite". The API is different.

Answer (score 0):

Did you progress with your question?. I got one project in the list but because I singed in for a free Google Maps Engine account. That allows you to créate just one project. 
But I was looking for accessing "my places" maps.

Answer (score 0):

When you mention that they are just available on the Maps Engine Pro (paid for) version, do you mean that the user who owns the maps has to upgrade or yourself, as a developer that want's to access user's maps, have?.

I wouldn't mind to pay (a reasonable price) for it in order to get my app working again. But I don't think most of my app's users would.

Could you check if it worked that way?